# Problems installing pytables on M1 Mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew, pytables

I'm trying to install pytables on an M1 Mac (MacOS 12.6.1, python 3.11 and hdf5 1.12.2 installed using homebrew). Following the advice in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74276925 I did the following:

```
pip install cython
brew install hdf5
brew install c-blosc
export HDF5_DIR=/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5 
export BLOSC_DIR=/opt/homebrew/opt/c-blosc
pip install tables
```

`pip install tables` produces the following output:

```
Collecting tables
  Using cached tables-3.7.0.tar.gz (8.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from tables) (1.24.0)
Collecting numexpr>=2.6.2
  Using cached numexpr-2.8.4-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (89 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from tables) (22.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: tables
  Building wheel for tables (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for tables (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [307 lines of output]
      Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
      AssertionError:
      /var/folders/82/c0s0s7md2m1c5nzd6s08j1tn09h343/T/lzo_version_dateuyld430w.c:2:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'lzo_version_date' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          lzo_version_date();
          ^
      1 error generated.
      /var/folders/82/c0s0s7md2m1c5nzd6s08j1tn09h343/T/lzo_version_date4yl230lw.c:2:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'lzo_version_date' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          lzo_version_date();
          ^
      1 error generated.
      /var/folders/82/c0s0s7md2m1c5nzd6s08j1tn09h343/T/BZ2_bzlibVersionowbloxlk.c:2:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'BZ2_bzlibVersion' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          BZ2_bzlibVersion();
          ^
      1 error generated.
      cpuinfo failed, assuming no CPU features: No module named 'cpuinfo'
      * Using Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 25 2022, 13:57:33) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)]
      * Found cython 0.29.32
      * USE_PKGCONFIG: True
      * Found HDF5 headers at ``/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/include``, library at ``/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/lib``.
      * Could not find LZO 2 headers and library; disabling support for it.
      * Could not find LZO 1 headers and library; disabling support for it.
      * Could not find bzip2 headers and library; disabling support for it.
      * pkg-config header dirs for blosc: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/c-blosc/1.21.3/include
      * pkg-config library dirs for blosc: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/c-blosc/1.21.3/lib
      * Found blosc headers at ``/opt/homebrew/Cellar/c-blosc/1.21.3/include``, library at ``/opt/homebrew/Cellar/c-blosc/1.21.3/lib``.
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-311/tables

[snip]

      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk -DNDEBUG=1 -DHAVE_BLOSC_LIB=1 -Ihdf5-blosc/src -I/usr/local/include -I/sw/include -I/opt/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/include -I/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/include -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/c-blosc/1.21.3/include -I/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c tables/utilsextension.c -o build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-311/tables/utilsextension.o -Isrc -DH5_USE_18_API -DH5Acreate_vers=2 -DH5Aiterate_vers=2 -DH5Dcreate_vers=2 -DH5Dopen_vers=2 -DH5Eclear_vers=2 -DH5Eprint_vers=2 -DH5Epush_vers=2 -DH5Eset_auto_vers=2 -DH5Eget_auto_vers=2 -DH5Ewalk_vers=2 -DH5E_auto_t_vers=2 -DH5Gcreate_vers=2 -DH5Gopen_vers=2 -DH5Pget_filter_vers=2 -DH5Pget_filter_by_id_vers=2 -DH5Tarray_create_vers=2 -DH5Tget_array_dims_vers=2 -DH5Z_class_t_vers=2 -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
      tables/utilsextension.c:8032:52: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'hsize_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') and 'long long' [-Wsign-compare]
              __pyx_t_2 = (((__pyx_v_maxdims[__pyx_v_i]) == -1LL) != 0);
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^  ~~~~
      tables/utilsextension.c:12367:33: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'hsize_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wsign-compare]
        for (__pyx_t_4 = 0; __pyx_t_4 < __pyx_t_3; __pyx_t_4+=1) {
                            ~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~
      tables/utilsextension.c:15186:35: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
          for (__pyx_t_5 = 0; __pyx_t_5 < __pyx_t_4; __pyx_t_5+=1) {
                              ~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~
      tables/utilsextension.c:15413:52: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'hsize_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') and 'long long' [-Wsign-compare]
              __pyx_t_3 = (((__pyx_v_maxdims[__pyx_v_j]) == -1LL) != 0);
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^  ~~~~
      tables/utilsextension.c:22030:23: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _err_stackitem'
          while ((exc_info->exc_type == NULL || exc_info->exc_type == Py_None) &&
                  ~~~~~~~~  ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22030:53: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _err_stackitem'
          while ((exc_info->exc_type == NULL || exc_info->exc_type == Py_None) &&
                                                ~~~~~~~~  ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22044:23: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _err_stackitem'
          *type = exc_info->exc_type;
                  ~~~~~~~~  ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22046:21: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _err_stackitem'
          *tb = exc_info->exc_traceback;
                ~~~~~~~~  ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22060:26: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _err_stackitem'
          tmp_type = exc_info->exc_type;
                     ~~~~~~~~  ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22062:24: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _err_stackitem'
          tmp_tb = exc_info->exc_traceback;
                   ~~~~~~~~  ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22063:15: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _err_stackitem'
          exc_info->exc_type = type;
          ~~~~~~~~  ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22065:15: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _err_stackitem'
          exc_info->exc_traceback = tb;
          ~~~~~~~~  ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22147:30: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _err_stackitem'
              tmp_type = exc_info->exc_type;
                         ~~~~~~~~  ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22149:28: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _err_stackitem'
              tmp_tb = exc_info->exc_traceback;
                       ~~~~~~~~  ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22150:19: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _err_stackitem'
              exc_info->exc_type = local_type;
              ~~~~~~~~  ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22152:19: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _err_stackitem'
              exc_info->exc_traceback = local_tb;
              ~~~~~~~~  ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22201:43: warning: 'ob_shash' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                  hash1 = ((PyBytesObject*)s1)->ob_shash;
                                                ^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/cpython/bytesobject.h:7:5: note: 'ob_shash' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
          Py_DEPRECATED(3.11) Py_hash_t ob_shash;
          ^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/pyport.h:336:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22202:43: warning: 'ob_shash' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                  hash2 = ((PyBytesObject*)s2)->ob_shash;
                                                ^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/cpython/bytesobject.h:7:5: note: 'ob_shash' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
          Py_DEPRECATED(3.11) Py_hash_t ob_shash;
          ^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/pyport.h:336:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22347:26: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _err_stackitem'
          tmp_type = exc_info->exc_type;
                     ~~~~~~~~  ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22349:24: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _err_stackitem'
          tmp_tb = exc_info->exc_traceback;
                   ~~~~~~~~  ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22350:15: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _err_stackitem'
          exc_info->exc_type = *type;
          ~~~~~~~~  ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:22352:15: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _err_stackitem'
          exc_info->exc_traceback = *tb;
          ~~~~~~~~  ^
      tables/utilsextension.c:23020:5: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _frame'
          __Pyx_PyFrame_SetLineNumber(py_frame, py_line);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      tables/utilsextension.c:445:62: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyFrame_SetLineNumber'
        #define __Pyx_PyFrame_SetLineNumber(frame, lineno)  (frame)->f_lineno = (lineno)
                                                            ~~~~~~~^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/pytypedefs.h:22:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct _frame'
      typedef struct _frame PyFrameObject;
                     ^
      6 warnings and 17 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tables
Failed to build tables
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tables, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65696724/2066572 suggests a possible solution to the error `no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _err_stackitem'` from the above output is to replace `pip install pytables` with `pip install --global-option build --global-option --force tables`. However, this fails with a different error:

```
Collecting tables
  Using cached tables-3.7.0.tar.gz (8.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [145 lines of output]
      DEPRECATION: --no-binary currently disables reading from the cache of locally built wheels. In the future --no-binary will not influence the wheel cache. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use the --no-cache-dir option. You can use the flag --use-feature=no-binary-enable-wheel-cache to test the upcoming behaviour. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11453
      Collecting setuptools>=42.0
        Using cached setuptools-65.6.3.tar.gz (2.6 MB)
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.38.4.tar.gz (67 kB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
        Using cached oldest-supported-numpy-2022.11.19.tar.gz (4.9 kB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting packaging
        Using cached packaging-22.0.tar.gz (125 kB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting Cython>=0.29.21
        Using cached Cython-0.29.32.tar.gz (2.1 MB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting numpy==1.23.2
        Using cached numpy-1.23.2.tar.gz (10.7 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [97 lines of output]
            Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
            AssertionError:
            <string>:71: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.23.2 may not yet support Python 3.11.
            Running from numpy source directory.
            <string>:86: DeprecationWarning:
      
              `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
              of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
              Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
              It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
              For more details, see:
                https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html
      
      
            running egg_info
            running build_src
            INFO: build_src
            creating numpy.egg-info
            writing numpy.egg-info/PKG-INFO
            writing dependency_links to numpy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
            writing entry points to numpy.egg-info/entry_points.txt
            writing top-level names to numpy.egg-info/top_level.txt
            writing manifest file 'numpy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
            /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py:643: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Custom 'build_py' does not implement 'get_data_files_without_manifest'.
            Please extend command classes from setuptools instead of distutils.
              warnings.warn(
            INFO: unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
                main()
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 333, in main
                json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
                return hook(config_settings)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
                return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
                self.run_setup()
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 484, in run_setup
                self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
                exec(code, locals())
              File "<string>", line 493, in <module>
              File "<string>", line 485, in setup_package
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 87, in setup
                return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
                return run_commands(dist)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
                dist.run_commands()
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 968, in run_commands
                self.run_command(cmd)
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
                super().run_command(command)
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 987, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/private/var/folders/82/c0s0s7md2m1c5nzd6s08j1tn09h343/T/pip-install-lomp8yz3/numpy_c85c0322750845cfba16acab1a65e8fa/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 25, in run
                _egg_info.run(self)
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 308, in run
                self.find_sources()
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 316, in find_sources
                mm.run()
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 560, in run
                self.add_defaults()
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 597, in add_defaults
                sdist.add_defaults(self)
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 107, in add_defaults
                self._add_defaults_build_sub_commands()
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 127, in _add_defaults_build_sub_commands
                self.filelist.extend(chain.from_iterable(files))
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 503, in extend
                self.files.extend(filter(self._safe_path, paths))
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 126, in <genexpr>
                files = (c.get_source_files() for c in cmds if hasattr(c, "get_source_files"))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 125, in <genexpr>
                cmds = (self.get_finalized_command(c) for c in missing_cmds)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 306, in get_finalized_command
                cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
                self.finalize_options()
              File "/private/var/folders/82/c0s0s7md2m1c5nzd6s08j1tn09h343/T/pip-install-lomp8yz3/numpy_c85c0322750845cfba16acab1a65e8fa/numpy/distutils/command/config_compiler.py", line 69, in finalize_options
                v = getattr(c, a)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py", line 157, in __getattr__
                return _build_ext.build_ext.__getattr__(self, name)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 105, in __getattr__
                raise AttributeError(attr)
            AttributeError: fcompiler. Did you mean: 'compiler'?
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> See above for output.
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Searches for the above error `AttributeError: fcompiler. Did you mean: 'compiler'?` have come up dry for me.

How do I install pytables in this environment? Is there a way to avoid building from source? If not, how do I get it to build successfully?

Comment: I would use conda/mamba

Comment: I'm reluctant to use conda here because I'm trying to set up a build system for a larger project and I don't want to add conda as a dependency for that project.

Comment: micromamba could be a good choice then. it's incredibly lightweight in a e.g., docker image

Comment: I'm not concerned with the size of Anaconda so much as its impact on portability. Pip is included in standard Python installations so it's relatively safe to assume it will be present.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs with Python 3.11 but not Python 3.10. Downgrading to Python 3.10 enables tables to install without error.

Comment: It happens with 3.10 as well.